# Why ParameterInfo::GetXXXCustomModifiers does not returns IsLong if the parameter is ByRef?

Tags: .net, reflection

Given a `ParameterInfo p` from this:

```
void foo(int modopt(IsLong) n);
```

`p.GetOptionalCustomModifiers()` returns a System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong; however, if the method signature happens to be:

```
void foo(out int modopt(IsLong) n);
```

It does not. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/503412/custom-type-modifiers-modreq-modopt-are-generally-inaccessible-through-the-current-reflection-api

It seems that this is already well known and Microsoft does not plan on fixing it in .NET 4.0